# Retrieve with selector the attribute "name" for the current td

Tags: jquery

I have a table with three columns, now I am able to select the third column of my table with this selector

```
$('td:eq(2)')
```

Now I have the content of my cell which is

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow" name="dbConnectionUrl"></span>
```

How can I retrieve the content of the attribut name. I tried it with the attr function but it does not work

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping in mind `<span>` ID:

```
$("#deleteRow").attr("name");
// or
$("#deleteRow").prop("name");
```

However, be careful with multiple elements with the same ID on the page, since **IDs should be unique**.

Respectively to your cell, the selector may look like:

```
$("td:eq(2) span").attr("name");
```

Comment: Good point.  I'm betting he has that ID in there multiple times.

Comment: @Gromer Yeah... Looks like a great possibility of that.

Comment: yes it is multiple, going to change! Thanks for the advice and the solution of my problem as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the span tag's name.. since it has an ID you can directly get it by

```
$('#deleteRow')[0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jquerys .attr('name') method?
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Just change your selector a bit:

`​$('table td:eq(2) #deleteRow')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.attr('name')`

That will give you the value of the name attribute.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/w3pQq/